# CSS align text left and right

Tags: css, flexbox

I have this:

```html
<div style="background-color: #25a0da; color: White; margin: 0">
  <h1 style="margin: 0  20px; padding: 0; line-height: 52px;">
    <span style="display: flex; justify-content: flex-start"><asp:Literal ID="litDateRange4" runat="server"></asp:Literal></span>
    <span style="display: flex; justify-content: flex-end"> <asp:Literal ID="litPendingProfit" runat="server"></asp:Literal></span>
  </h1>
</div>
```

I want the first span to be snapped to the left, and the second one to the right, which is working however they appear on different lines.

Quite new to flex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want the first span to be snapped to the left, and the second one to
>   the right

You can use the flexbox layout model to achieve that.

```css
h1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color: #25a0da; color: White; margin: 0">
  <h1 style="margin: 0  20px; padding: 0; line-height: 52px;">
    <span style="display: flex; justify-content: flex-start">aaa</span>
    <span style="display: flex; justify-content: flex-end"> bbb</span>
  </h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add

```
justify-content: space-between
```

to the parent element. In doing so, the children flexbox items will be aligned to opposite sides with space between them.